# does TensorFlow automatically use sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits when possible?

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say that I have some code such as:

```
out = tf.nn.softmax(x)  # shape (batch,time,n)
labels = ....  # reference labels of type (batch,time)->int
```

And then I define my loss as the Cross Entropy:

```
loss = -tf.log(tf.gather_nd(out, labels))
```

Will TensorFlow automatically replace the `loss` in the computation graph by this?

```
loss = sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(x, labels)
```

What type of optimizations can I expect that TensorFlow will apply?

Follow-up question: If TensorFlow doesn't do this optimization, how can I do it manually? Consider that I have a modular framework where I get some `out` tensor which could possibly be the output of a `softmax` operation, and I want to calculate Cross Entropy, and I want to use `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` if possible. How could I accomplish this? Can I do something like the following?

```
if out.op == "softmax":  # how to check this?
    x = out.op.sources[0]  # how to get this?
    loss = sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(x, labels)
else:
    loss = -tf.log(tf.gather_nd(out, labels))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow generally doesn't merge nodes together in the way you're hoping. This is because other code (e.g. fetching outputs when running) may depend on intermediate nodes like the softmax, so removing them behind the user's back would be confusing.

If you do want to do this optimization yourself as part of a higher-level framework, you can analyze the current graphdef, but there's no annotation in TF to tell you what the outputs are, since that can vary at runtime depending on how session.run is called.